# What are different ways to share data securely within network?

Tags: windows, security, share

What are the secure methods or technologies for securely share the highly confidential information within a network or intranet. I am open to any open source application or vendors that enable secure data sharing in intranet.
Platform : Windows

Answer (score 1):

PGP encryption for messages is perfect if you are sending out information. Its secure and the information can be signed so that the receivers can check the authenticity of the sender.

Email is also something that users are familiar with. They just need to have a proper mail client set up and press some buttons.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy